# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException with JAX-RS and Maven

Tags: java, maven, jersey, jax-rs

I assume it's a duplicate question, but I could not find a solution. I have developed a JAX-RS service with Maven.

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.diginreportengine.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>digin-report</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>DiginReportEngine</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
         <build>
        <finalName>Report</finalName>
    </build>

</project>
```

web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
                        version="3.0">    
    <display-name>DigIn Report Engine</display-name> 
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
             <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
             <param-value>com.diginreportengine.jersey.main</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet> 
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rs/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping> 
</web-app>
```

and the **Code:**

```
@Path("GetReport")
public class ReportService { 
    @GET
    @Path("{reportName}/{parameters}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response getReport(@PathParam("reportName") String reportName,@PathParam("parameters") String parameters) {

    }

    @GET
    @Path("{reportName}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response startEngine(@PathParam("reportName") String command) {
            return Response.status(200).entity("ok").build();
    }
}
```

**log:**

```
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.2.5 using APR version 1.5.1.
Mar 31, 2016 1:17:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
Mar 31, 2016 1:17:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016)
Mar 31, 2016 1:17:38 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8085"]
Mar 31, 2016 1:17:38 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Mar 31, 2016 1:17:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2121 ms
Mar 31, 2016 1:17:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 31, 2016 1:17:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
Mar 31, 2016 1:17:41 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mar 31, 2016 1:17:41 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [234] milliseconds.
Mar 31, 2016 1:17:44 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mar 31, 2016 1:17:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet jersey-serlvet as unavailable
Mar 31, 2016 1:17:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [jersey-serlvet] in web application [/DiginReport] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1308)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:518)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:499)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1038)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4997)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5289)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Mar 31, 2016 1:17:44 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8085"]
Mar 31, 2016 1:17:44 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Mar 31, 2016 1:17:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 5357 ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration is messy: You added the JAX-RS 2.0 dependency, but you are using Jersey 1.x configuration in your `web.xml` deployment descriptor.

I think you want to use Jersey 2.x, which is the reference implementation for the JAX-RS 2.0 specification.

### A quick overview

Jersey 1.x and Jersey 2.x use different package names:

- Jersey 1.x: `com.sun.jersey`
- Jersey 2.x: `org.glassfish.jersey`

Jersey 1.x and Jersey 2.x implement different versions of the JAX-RS specification:

- Jersey 1.x: [JSR 311 / JAX-RS 1.0](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=311) ([`jsr311-api`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/jsr311-api) artifact)
- Jersey 2.x: [JSR 339 / JAX-RS 2.0](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=339) ([`javax.ws.rs-api`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api) artifact)

### Fixing your dependencies

Change dependencies in your `pom.xml` to be as following:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <!-- if your container implements Servlet API older than 3.0, 
             use "jersey-container-servlet-core"  -->
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

For more details on Jersey modules and dependencies, have a look at the [documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/modules-and-dependencies.html).

### Fixing your deployment descriptor

You are using Tomcat 8.x, which [supports Servlet API 3.1](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html). For simple deployments, no `web.xml` deployment descriptor is necessary at all.

If you want, you can have an empty one, as following:

```xml
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
                        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">

 </web-app>
```

However, you'll need a custom [`Application`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html)/[`ResourceConfig`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html) subclass annotated with [`@ApplicationPath`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ApplicationPath.html) to define the base application URI for all Jersey resources configured in the application:

```java
@ApplicationPath("rs")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public MyApplication() {
        packages("com.diginreportengine.jersey.main");
    }
}
```

In case you are not providing `web.xml` deployment descriptor for your Maven based web application project, you need to configure your [`maven-war-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/) to ignore the missing `web.xml` file by setting `failOnMissingWebXml` configuration property to `false` in your project `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    ...
</plugins>
```

For more details on Jersey deployment and runtime environments, have a look at the [documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/modules-and-dependencies.html).

Comment: Parse error in application web.xml file at file:/C:/penktr/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/DiginReport/WEB-INF/web.xml

Comment: am finding hard, where to add this ? Application/ResourceConfig

Comment: @Sajeetharan Just add this class to any package of your project.

Comment: I did that, it still says cannot access resource

Comment: This is the error i am getting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36381812/requested-resource-not-available-jax-rs-service

Comment: @Sajeetharan So you could start Tomcat without errors, couldn't you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108077/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-cassio-mazzochi-molin).