# Requested resource not available jax-rs service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-rs

I wrote a jax-rs service using jersey, and the class is as follows,

I want to define the url for the following like this,

**One to get the reports by passing parameters**

> http://localhost:8085/DiginReport/rs/Reports/getreport/{test1:value,test2:value}

**One to start the Engine:**

> http://localhost:8085/DiginReport/rs/Reports/start

```
 @Path("Reports")
public class ReportService {

    @GET
    @Path("/getreport}/{parameters}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response getReport(@PathParam("reportName") String reportName,@PathParam("parameters") String parameters) throws KettleXMLException, KettleMissingPluginsException, JSONException, UnknownParamException {
        JSONArray jsonarr;
        return Response.status(200).entity("ok").build();
    }


    @GET
    @Path("{start}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response startEngine(@PathParam("start") String command) {
        return Response.status(200).entity("ok").build();
    }
}
```

When i type this in url , it says resource not avaliable,
http://localhost:8085/DiginReport/rs/Reports/start

Comment: `@Path("/getreport}/{parameters}")` is this correct because `getReports` has a traling `}`?

Comment: how it needs to be changed?

Comment: it should be `@Path("/getreport/{parameters}")`

Comment: ok, that i will change, why does the other url does not work?

Comment: Can you try like  `@Path("/command/{start}")` and invoke using `http://localhost:8085/DiginReport/rs/Reports/command/start`

Comment: No its the same HTTP Status 404 - /DiginReport/rs/Reports/command/start

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108069/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-karthikeyan-vaithilingam).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code.

I would also consider the following things:

Pass Json data as `application/json` instead of string as path parameter (note that you need to escape.

Use another method than `GET` to start the engine (e.g. `POST`), since get should be only used to retrieve data.

Use resources within the URL instead of `start` or `getreports`.

```
@Path("Reports")
public class ReportService {

    @GET
    @Path("/getreport/{parameters}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response getReport(@PathParam("parameters") String parameters) throws KettleXMLException, KettleMissingPluginsException, JSONException, UnknownParamException {
        JSONArray jsonarr;
        return Response.status(200).entity("ok").build();
    }


    @GET
    @Path("/start")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response startEngine() {
        return Response.status(200).entity("ok").build();
    }
}
```

Comment: it was fixed when i deployed as standalone app.